# Undo remove word from autocorrect

Tags: keyboard, gboard, auto-correct, 8.0-oreo, text-prediction

In the newest versions of Android, you can click and hold a suggested predictive/autocorrected word, and drag it into a bin (title "remove") to prevent it from being suggested again.

I accidentally deleted the word "I", so now when I type "i" it doesn't automatically autocorrect to "I".

Two related questions:

1. I tried shaking my phone to undo the accidental word removal (like I would undo things on an iPhone), but it didn't do anything. Is there a way I could've undone my action immediately after it happened?
2. Now that it's a few days after the face, how to do I add "I" back to the suggested words without having to completely erase all the things my keyboard has learned about my typing habits?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to type the deleted word, in your case the "I", many times in a sentence or sentences. Gboard will re-learn about it, and start suggesting it again.

Answer (score -1):

Reset personal data on your keyboard, so your keyboard data will be reset.

Settings > Device > Language and Input > Press the keyboard that you use > clear personal data

Comment: I use Gboard (tagged in my question). I don't want to delete all info from my keyboard (also in my question)